# Checking presence of an element in a list using 2 params and a lambda function in C++

Tags: c++, list, lambda

I'm trying to check the presence of **8** in a list of `1,2,3,4,5` using the `any_of`

```
  list<int> mylist{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
  int arg = 8;
  bool is_present = any_of(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), [&arg,&elt](auto& arg,auto& elt) {return arg == elt; });
  cout << "Is 8 present? " << is_present << endl;
```

But I get error in the lambda function.
As I try to correct the error it gives various errors like

`In lambda function ‘elt’ is not captured`

or

`lambda parameter ‘arg’ previously declared as a capture`

How to correctly arrange the lambda function?
Note that I must solve it using 2 parameters and a lambda function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using arg and elt both as capture and parameters of the lambda, using the lamda inside any_of the argument of lambda is implictly a reference to the content of the container so you have to modify your lambda like so:

```
    bool is_present = std::any_of(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), [&arg](int& elt) {return arg == elt; });
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
// capture arg, and check every element (elt) equals to arg or not
bool is_present = any_of(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), [arg](auto elt) {return arg == elt; });
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GEPJtO2hCKphVyCJ)

Comment: Good in the way of understanding the function lambdas as it shows one does not have to use the `&` ref operators for this particular operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve it with two parameters (if you mean two parameters to your lambda function). The lambda function used in `any_of` must take one parameter by [definiton](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Here's how to do it

```
bool is_present = any_of(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), [=](auto elt){ return arg == elt; });
```

Comment: Didn't know I could put a function `=` inside the `captured variables` section. It works. How to interpret this usage of `captured variables` ?

Comment: Ops. NutCracker has just explained it in the post below.

Answer (score 2):

```
[&arg,&elt](auto& arg,auto& elt)
```

One, there are no `elt` in the surrounding scope to capture. Two, the predicate passed to `any_of` must take one argument. Three, a parameter would shadow a capture of the same name.

```
[&arg](auto& elt)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It has worked the problem out. I have to select SeventhSon84's post as answer though as it came earlier.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)'s 3rd parameter is **unary predicate** which means that the lambda can receive only one argument which would be the element of the list in the current iteration.

Furthermore, you need to capture your `arg` variable in order to use it in comparison inside the lambda expression. Both capture-by-value:

- `[arg](...) {...}` captures only `arg` variable by value
- `[=](...) {...}` captures all variables in the current scope by value

and capture-by-reference:

- `[&arg](...) {...}` captures only `arg` variable by reference
- `[&](...) {...}` captures all variables in the current scope by reference

will do the work.

Eventually, the following would work:

```cpp
bool is_present = std::any_of(
    mylist.begin(), mylist.end(),
    [arg] (auto el) {
        return arg == el;
    }
);
```

Comment: Just checked in to have a look at the usage of those lambda expressions. Two questions: 1- In the section *capture-by-value* could there be a typo? It looks like it should have been *capture-by-reference* 2- What's the difference between and when does it matter capturing a variable by value and by reference?

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen yes, you are right about the typo... the difference between capturing by value and by reference is that when capturing by value, you make copies which in case of large objects is a problem. That's one of the differences.